# how to skip entries that are NULL in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with two things on my news feed.

I'm trying to get a news feed show all database entries, but some don't have a date because they are some sort of sticked news feeds that aren't date related. but the problem is that it still pushes a enter/empty line for those. How can i make my feed just skip the date column if there is no date entry in that id, but still show the news?

and second question, how can i add a span class to the date that is returning to the feed?

this is my code for loading up the database:

```
<?php   
                // Grab the data from our people table

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"newsstory\">";
                    echo "<p>";
                    echo $row['date'] . " " . "<br />";
                    echo $row['news'];
                    echo "</p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }


            ?>
```

thanks for the help guys!

edit: as it might be that my upload script uploads a empty space when nothing is entered, i just added my upload script to be sure:

```
<?php

// Call our connection file
require("includes/conn.php");

$date=$_POST['date'];
$news=$_POST['news'];

$query="Insert into news (date, news) values ('$date', '$news')";  

mysql_query($query) or die ('error updating database'); 


echo "database updated with '$date', '$news'";
?>
```

Comment: First thing, stop using `mysql_` functions and switch to either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: ...and prepared statements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
echo $row['date'] . " " . "<br />";
```

with

```
echo !empty($row['date']) ? ("<span>". $row['date'] . " </span><br />") : '';
```

This way you'll still display all news, but the date line will be displayed only for news having a not null date.

Comment: this results in showing all posts, but no date at the one that has an entry and showing the span class at the ones that doesn't have a date...

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly. Hope I understood well.

Comment: when i try this it doesn't display the date in the span but the word foo..., other then that it works like i want it too ;)

Comment: So I didn't understand what you wanted. You want the date in a span if there is a date, but what do you want if there is no date ? The word foo is just an dummy data, don't paste it like that :)

Comment: lol i was already thinking what the hell :p yeah you are correct, the thing i want is when there is a date entry it should display inside the span class and if there is no date it should just skip the date row without showing the class or an empty line, so that there are no brakes underneath my devider because there i no date

Comment: whahaha i was close at editing but now i see while i had error :p i was using this ;)  echo empty($row['date']) ? ('<span class=\"date\">'$row['date'] '</span>');

Comment: weird, again no date displayed when there i one :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66989/discussion-between-x-l-ant-and-fgod).

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a condition in your loop:

**EDIT**

Based on OP comment.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $date = "No date";
    if (!empty($row['date'])) { //Check here
        $date = $row["date"];
    }
    echo "<div class=\"newsstory\">";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<span>" . $date . "</span> " . "<br />"; //Added span
    echo $row['news'];
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: this looks perfect but i am not getting the results anymore where there is no date attached to the id of the news...

Comment: I thought you want to skip the whole row... See my edited answer.

Comment: something like that but then without the no date thing and just skipping the whole row from displaying ;)

Comment: But that was my previous answer. So, what should happens, where no date? Skip the whole row, or just show something else in or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   if($row['date'] != ""){
    ------------------
     -------------
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this ??

```
if($row['date']!="")
{
 echo $row['date'] . " " . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap an

```
if (!is_null($row['date'])) {}
```

Around the date echo

Comment: he still shows the span and enters the empty space in date when there is nothing in date entered...

unless there might be a problem in my upload script which might upload something while there is nothing entered in the text box when uploading it...

i'll add the upload script to my npost so you can take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC
```

-for skipping the entire row with a `NULL` value on `date`.

repeat `date IS NOT NULL` for each column you need

Comment: that results in this error: Could not access DB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date IS NOT NULL' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

if you have taken date column's datatype as a date than if date you not entering than its default entry stored in table is 0000-00-00, thats why i have added condition for that..
Try it once, definitely you will get perfect output whatever you want

```html
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $ddate=$row['date'];
  if($ddate!='' || $ddate!=NULL || $ddate!='0000-00-00')
  {
   echo "<div class=\"newsstory\">";
   echo "<p>";
      echo "<div class='span'>".$row['date']."</div><br />"; //comment if below line you uncomment
   //echo "<span>".$row['date']."</span><br />"; //uncomment if you want span tag instead of div with span class
      echo $row['news'];
   echo "</p>";
   echo "</div>";
  }
}
```